# MySQL request on joining table: keep secondary table separate

Tags: mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables, `housing`, `hp` (joining table) and `photos`.

I want to be able to link each `housing` item to the list of `photo` items that are connected to it via `hp`, ideally in one MySQL request.

Currently I have tried the following:

```sql
SELECT housing.id, housing.title, photos.url
FROM housing
JOIN hp ON housing.id=hp.housing_id
JOIN photos ON hp.photo_id=photos.photo_id ;
```

But using this, if one `housing` element has 3 `photos` elements, that `housing` element is returned 3 times.

I'm using PHP to send/handle the queries, so is there a way to return an array of `photos` elements for each `housing` element?

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN

Comment: @JayBlanchard I wasn't sure if you could use them if you had a joining table I'll try it :)

Comment: Seeing as you're using PHP, just handle issues of data display there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT housing.id, housing.title, group_concat(photos.url) as url
FROM housing
JOIN hp ON housing.id=hp.housing_id
JOIN photos ON hp.photo_id=photos.photo_id 
GROUP BY housing.id, housing.title
```

You will get a comma separated list of the photos.
If there is a case there are not any photos for a housing item then change to `LEFT` join.

Comment: If there are no photos, do I change both `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s?

Comment: If there is always a match in table hp there is no need to change that join to LEFT, so change only the 2nd.

Comment: @JessicaChambers yes, `LEFT JOIN` will get matches on the left irrespective of the  right.